# how to compile Android NDK with gradle that contain ARM assembly optimizaions

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, arm

I have an Android NDK project that has arm assembly optimizations files (.S), gradle compiles src c files (.c) but not .S , how to "tell" gradle to compile the .S files too?

I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.3.1 stable
- Gradle 2.5 with experimental plugin 0.2.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these are supported yet by AS and the experimental plugin.

What you can do is to switch to use `ndk-buil`d yourself with standard *Android.mk*/*Application.mk* files.

Set this inside your *build.gradle*, so it will not try to compile your code, and it will get your .so files from *src/main/libs/*:

```
android.sources{
    main.jni {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/none'] // [] could be set instead but will disable even symbol resolution inside the editor
        }
    }
    main.jniLibs {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        }
    }
}
```